# Inconvertable Types Android

Tags: android

I am getting a weird error. In my code I am trying to cast a WorkoutDetailFragment to an object which is of type WorkoutDetailFragment. Here is the code for WorkoutDetailFragment:

```
package com.hfad.workout;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class WorkoutDetailFragment extends Fragment {
    private long workoutId;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        if(savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            workoutId = savedInstanceState.getLong("workoutId");
        }
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        com.hfad.workout.StopwatchFragment stopwatchFragment = new com.hfad.workout.StopwatchFragment();
        ft.replace(R.id.stopwatch_container, stopwatchFragment);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.commit();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_detail, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        View view = getView();
        if(view != null)
        {
            TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
            Workout workout = Workout.workouts[(int) workoutId];
            title.setText(workout.getName());
            TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDescription);
            description.setText(workout.getDescription());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        savedInstanceState.putLong("workoutId", workoutId);
    }

    public void setWorkout(long id)
    {
        this.workoutId = id;
    }
}
```

The error is occurring in this class named DetailActivity saying that: "Inconvertable types; cannot cast 'android.app.Fragment' to 'com.hfad.workout.WorkoutDetailFragment'. Here is the code for DetailActivity, I have a comment on top of the piece of code that has an error:

```
    package com.hfad.workout;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class DetailActivity extends Activity
    {
        public static final String EXTRA_WORKOUT_ID = "id";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
            //This is where the error occurs: 
WorkoutDetailFragment workoutDetailFragment = (WorkoutDetailFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_frag);
            int workoutId = (int) getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_WORKOUT_ID);
            workoutDetailFragment.setWorkout(workoutId);
        }
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, let me know if any other code or further explanation is needed :)

Comment: Make DetailActivity extend `AppCompatActivity`, and use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of getFragmentManager().

Comment: thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [ActivityCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html) instead of just plain old activity if you're using the support [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html). The regular Activity knows nothing about the support fragment and they don't share any common ancestors - just conform to the same interface (not an actual `Interface`).

Comment: Thank you as well!